# Firebase notification not working in my android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android app where I want to include firebase notification. What I am doing are these codes

This is the Firebase instance id Class

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("token", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {


        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

}
```

FirebaseMessageingService.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import digifrizz.dealer.com.sargam.Constant;
import digifrizz.dealer.com.sargam.R;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Created by HP on 28-09-2018.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.

            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }
            // Check if message contains a notification payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }

            // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
            // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

        }

    }

    private void handleNow() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constant.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line..."))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);


    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    }
```

This is the manifest file

```
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_activitty_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".firebaseservices.FirebaseService"
        android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".firebaseservices.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "digifrizz.dealer.com.sargam"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What I am doing is sending through firebase cloud message console and postman following this article https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3, but is working on android app. But the postman reply gives success

Also, I am getting the firebase device token from this code in main activity oncreate

```
String firebaseId= String.valueOf(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        Log.d("firebasetoken", "Refreshed token: " + firebaseId);
```

Can anyone please help me solving this problem .

Comment: Did you send to emulator or real device?

Comment: I have heard about that some devices  disabled push notification port at default

Comment: It is a real device

Comment: Is the device's API level 26+? (Oreo and above) 
Are you able to see any logs with the remote message's payload?

Comment: Actualy no logs and code service not invoking even if break point  is used

Comment: Yeah,that might be the problem,better to check if the potential Message ports are available.

Comment: I checked in emulator also there also its not working

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the firebase project ID and pass it as a parameter to the getToken() method

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(FCM_APP_ID, "FCM");
```